# PHP switch case statement giving problem on first loop

Tags: php, debugging, switch-statement

I was trying to do some exercises in PHP for school and I ran into this...

My code:

```
<?php

$arr = [ 3, 4, 5, 6, "apple", 7.2, -10, "banana", 5, 5.1, 6, "okke" ];

$item = 0;
while ( $item < count($arr) ) {
    echo $item." - ";

    switch ( $item ) {
        case $arr[ $item ] == 5:
            echo $arr[ $item ]." --> This is 5<br />";
            break;

        case $arr[ $item ] == 6:
            echo $arr[ $item ]." --> This is 6<br />";
            break;

        default:
            echo " --> Not found<br />";
    }

    $item++;
}
?>
```

This is the result I get:

```
0 - 3 --> This is 5
1 - --> Not found
2 - 5 --> This is 5
3 - 6 --> This is 6
4 - --> Not found
5 - --> Not found
6 - --> Not found
7 - --> Not found
8 - 5 --> This is 5
9 - --> Not found
10 - 6 --> This is 6
11 - --> Not found
```

But in the first line I should get:

> 0 - --> Not found

Why is the Switch not working correctly??

Comment: This is not so good usage of `switch`. If you're using it, there should be `switch ( $arr[$item] )`. Than is `case`s you can use simple `case 5: ...; case 6: ...; default` without comparison.

Comment: Thank you @pavel I resolved using switch($arr[$item]), but why does it work like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did the switch wrongly. :)

The `switch ( $item ) {` should contain item which you are searching for.

Fixed code here:

```
<?php

$arr = [ 3, 4, 5, 6, "apple", 7.2, -10, "banana", 5, 5.1, 6, "okke" ];

$item = 0;
while ( $item < count($arr) ) {
    echo $item." - ";
    echo $arr[$item];

    switch ( $arr[ $item ] ) {
        case 5:
            echo $arr[ $item ]." --> This is 5<br />";
            break;

        case 6:
            echo $arr[ $item ]." --> This is 6<br />";
            break;

        default:
            echo " --> Not found<br />";
    }

    $item++;
}
?>
```

Or this would be another solution (not ideal one but I hope this would provide you more examples :)

```
<?php

$arr = [ 3, 4, 5, 6, "apple", 7.2, -10, "banana", 5, 5.1, 6, "okke" ];

$item = 0;
while ( $item < count($arr) ) {
    echo $item." - ";
    echo $arr[$item];

    switch ( true ) {
        case $arr[ $item ] === 5:
            echo $arr[ $item ]." --> This is 5<br />";
            break;

        case $arr[ $item ] === 6:
            echo $arr[ $item ]." --> This is 6<br />";
            break;

        default:
            echo " --> Not found<br />";
    }

    $item++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I resolved using `switch($arr[$item])`